# Troubles with matrices as arguments in functions

Tags: c, function, matrix, return, arguments

I want to pass a matrix into a function and then return the same matrix to another function.
This is part of my code:

```
int** inizializzazione_matrice(int matrice1[][MAX_COLONNE]){
int i = 0, k = 0;

while(i < MAX_RIGHE){
    k = 0;
    while(k < MAX_COLONNE){
        matrice1[i][k] = i;
        k++;
    }
    i++;
}

return matrice1;}
```

I call this function like that:

```
stampa_matrice(inizializzazione_matrice(matrice1));
```

`stampa_matrice` is a void function that takes the same input of `inizializzazione_matrice` as argument.

Their declarations are:

```
int** inizializzazione_matrice(int matrice1[][MAX_COLONNE]);
void stampa_matrice(int matrice1[][MAX_COLONNE]);
```

The error comes out at the `inizializzazione_matrice` `return matrice1;` with the error code: `int (*matrice1)[10] Error type value doesn't match the function type`.

I don't understand why, since the call of `inizializzazione_matrice` has been done in the same way and it works. I tried using the double pointer as argument too, but it's the same and i have an older code in eclipse that works just fine in the same way (that's the scary part).
Am i missing something? If you need further infos please tell me!

Comment: You don't need to return `matrice1`, changes are made in-place, `inizializzazione_matrice` could be `void`; plus, `MAX_COLONNE` should be passed separated from `matrice1`

Comment: Also, if you are not compiling with warnings enabled, do so, they will provide additional information in this case. At a minimum use `-Wall -Wextra` which will further help identify mismatches in declarations/arguments/etc.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that i disabled the warnings on visual studio, because they were blocking my compiling for a whim of VS. I'll check and re-enable it just in case

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simpler way:

```
void inizializzazione_matrice(int **matrice1, max_righe, max_colonne)
{
  int i = 0, k = 0;

  while (i < max_righe) {
    k = 0;
    while (k < max_colonne) {
      matrice1[i][k] = i;
      k++;
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

No need to return `matrice1`, as it is passed by parameter (not by value).

You can do it better (code speaking) with two nested `for`:

```
void inizializzazione_matrice(int **matrice1, max_righe, max_colonne)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < max_righe)
    for (int k = 0; k < max_colonne)
      matrice1[i][k] = i;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. I activated email notification but nothing arrived via email. I can already do it easily without the return, but using it was my purpose. I find it more "organized" and fast to do in this way. Or am i wrong? Anyway i didn't use the for because my prof at university doesn't want to see it in our code and i'm avoiding to use it to prevent to take the habit

Comment: There's a lot of discussions about this argument, you can't pass an array to a function by value, you use a pointer; you can allocate a new array and return its pointer (this won't change the original array). The while construct is ok.

Comment: But why i can pass the parameter just fine at the call of inizializzazione_matrice? isn't the same as the return value to a pointer?

Comment: You don't have to return the pointer to `matrice1`, because the caller scope of `inizializzazione_matrice` already has it, it's the first parameter of the method.

Comment: i wanted to return it for the stampa_matrice function, that i called like that: "stampa_matrice(inizializzazione_matrice(matrice1));" or is it better to call it separately?

Comment: it's better to call them separately; remember that the two functions don't know how much large is the array